# What the meaning of these different types of namespace in c#

Tags: c#

I want to know the difference for this code

I know the code below contains namespaces

```
using SampleAngularApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

and also I know the below code contains a namespace

```
namespace SampleAngularApp.Controllers
{
    .......
}
```

What is the difference between these two types of namespaces?

Comment: I think you could even search for a minute to recognize the diffrence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `namespace SampleAngularApp.Controllers` is *defining* a namespace (or scope, or virtual segregation). This might be the first instance of the namespace, or it might be adding to the same namespace that is already defined elsewhere. These namespaces (scopes) are independent of physical code boundaries, i.e. the same namespace can exist in two or more different assemblies.

The lines `using SampleAngularApp.Models;` etc. are *importing* a namespace, IOW making that scope available to the local code. You don't need to use `using` statements, you could specify the full namespace everytime you use a type or reference a method/property, but that is just lunacy. Putting that line in your code is potentially only one half of the process - you also have to add a reference to the assembly that has the code within the namespace that you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the 'using' key . You are telling the compiler you want to use this namespace and every class under this namespace in your class

When using 'namespace' key you are telling the compiler this section between the '{' and '}' is my namespace for my class , so when you'd use your class in another namespace you need to add it in using statement.

ex:

```
Using SampleAngularApp.Controllers
```

then i can use all your classes in 'SampleAngularApp.Controllers' namespace

Comment: "use" key ?? Is it have c# ?

Comment: 'Use' key and 'use' statement same meaning..

Comment: I think you mean "using", not "use"

Comment: my bad ... wow i guess its Monday again

Answer (score 1):

With

`namespace SampleAngularApp.Controllers
{
.......
}`

You are declaring a namespace which is a scope that let you organize code and prevents create globally unique types.

With

> using SampleAngularApp.Models;
>
> using System;
>
> using System.Collections.Generic;

You are telling the Compiler that this block of code is using above namespaces and all of classes are `accessible`.

Means that you can use every thing in their scope in your application.